# Detect new comment is added with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect new comments on a post and add a notification that there is a new comment, now I have only the code for posting

```
$("#comment").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("comment.php",{"comment" : $("#comment_text").val()},function() {
        $("#comment_text").val("");
    });
});
```

How can I detect that there are new comments ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.change` event to your element, which you want to watch
  https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to get new comments from other users of the site.

One simple possibility is to return new comments from the server as a result to your post like this (updated your code):

```
$("#comment").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("comment.php",{"comment" : $("#comment_text").val()},function(responseData) {
        $("#comment_text").val("");
        //now use response data with new comments
        //the structure depends on you
        for(var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++){
            $("your_comment_target").append(responseData[i].message);
        }
    });
});
```

`responseData` is created (probably read from database) on server (php). More on returning data to post `success` here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

I assume `responseData` is in form of `JSON`, very simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/uk3nmdtr/1/

Personally I would prefer to have separate "refresh" function that would load comments using ajax, something like:

```
$.get("getnewcomments.php", {articleId: /*Id or some other data here*/},
    function(responseData){
        //use response same as above
    });
```

Advanced scenario would be using `WebSockets` or some library to get "realtime" refresh.